# How to filter a certain type of python list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings. Each string has the same length/number of characters in the format
`xyzw01.ext` or `xyzv02.ext`, etc.

For example

```
list 1: ['ABCJ01.ext','CDEJ02.ext','ADEJ01.ext','CDEJ01.ext','ABCJ02.ext','CDEJ03.ext']
list 2: ['ABCJ01.ext','ADEJ01.ext','CDEJ01.ext','RPNJ01.ext','PLEJ01.ext']
```

I would like from these lists to build new lists with only the strings with highest number.
So from list 1 I would like to get

```
['ADEJ01.ext','ABCJ02.ext','CDEJ03.ext']
```

while for list 2 I would like to get  the same list since all numbers are 01.

Is there a "simple" way of achieving this?

Comment: Please see the [intro tour,](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) the [help center,](https://stackoverflow.com/help) this post on [how to ask a good question,](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Asking "how do I do X?" is considered off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

```
from collections import defaultdict

def fun(lst):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for x in lst:
        res[x[:4]].append(x)
    return [max(res[x], key=lambda x: x[4:6]) for x in res]


lst = ['ABCJ01.ext','CDEJ02.ext','ADEJ01.ext','CDEJ01.ext','ABCJ02.ext','CDEJ03.ext']
lst2 = ['ABCJ01.ext','ADEJ01.ext','CDEJ01.ext','RPNJ01.ext','PLEJ01.ext']

print(fun(lst))
print(fun(lst2))
```

**Output:**

```
['ABCJ02.ext', 'CDEJ03.ext', 'ADEJ01.ext']
['ABCJ01.ext', 'ADEJ01.ext', 'CDEJ01.ext', 'RPNJ01.ext', 'PLEJ01.ext']
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use an intermediate data structure, like a `dict` - sort the list items into buckets based on the first part of their names, and then take the maximum number for each bucket. We can just use the built-in `max()` without a key, since as-given lexicographic sorting works to find the largest. If that's not sufficient, you could use more regex to take the number out of the item and use it as the key instead.

```
import re

def filter_list(lst):
    prefixes = {}
    for item in lst:
        # use regex to isolate the non-numeric characters at the start of the string
        prefix = re.match(r'^([^0-9]*)', item).group(1)
        # make a bucket based on each prefix, and put the item in it
        prefixes.setdefault(prefix, [])
        prefixes[prefix].append(item)
    # make a list comprehension taking the maximum item from each bucket
    return [max(value) for value in prefixes.values()]
```

```
>>> a = ['ABCJ01.ext','CDEJ02.ext','ADEJ01.ext','CDEJ01.ext','ABCJ02.ext','CDEJ03.ext']
>>> b = ['ABCJ01.ext','ADEJ01.ext','CDEJ01.ext','RPNJ01.ext','PLEJ01.ext']
>>> filter_list(a)
['ABCJ02.ext', 'CDEJ03.ext', 'ADEJ01.ext']
>>> filter_list(b)
['ABCJ01.ext', 'ADEJ01.ext', 'CDEJ01.ext', 'RPNJ01.ext', 'PLEJ01.ext']
```

In python 3.7+, this should preserve the order of list from the *first occurrence of each prefix* (i.e. `CDEJ03.ext` will precede `ADEJ01.ext` in the output because `CDEJ02.ext` precedes it in the input).
To get the output in the exact same order as the original list, behavior, you'd want to explicitly reassign the key instead of using `.setdefault()`, perhaps with a pattern like `prefixes[prefix] = prefixes[prefix] if prefix in prefixes else []`.